# only logged in customer should access a page in oc

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

I want to display an information page on certain conditions like
 1. Customer Group ID is 2
 2. Customer is logged in

If these two conditions meets then, display information page(id-12) Course1.

I am trying to do it in catalog/controller/information.php

```
$id = $this->customer->getGroupId();
if (($this->customer->isLogged()) &&  ($information_id == 12) && ($id==2)) { 
    $this->redirect($this->url->link('account/account', '', 'SSL'));    
}
```

But this is not working, giving error 
**Fatal error: Call to undefined method ControllerInformationInformation::redirect()**

Where i am going wrong. plz suggest

Answer (score 2):

Use `$this->response->redirect($this->url->link('account/account', '', 'SSL'));`
Instead of `$this->redirect($this->url->link('account/account', '', 'SSL'));`

**EDIT**
The `redirect()` method is defined in `class Response`. You can do `$this->redirect()` only if you have defined `redirect()` method in your current class.

**Edit 2**

If you want to display informative pages only to logged in customer then try this condition

```
if (!$this->customer->isLogged()) {
    $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('account/login', '', 'SSL'));
}
```

Just Put It After

```
public function index() {  ...
```

Comment: Yes, redirection is happening now. Thank you. But without login also the page is visible :(. Condition is not working

Comment: What is `$this->customer->isLogged()` returning?

Comment: `$this->customer->isLogged()` will return customer id. Returns 0 if customer is not logged in. Is same as `$this->customer->getId()`

Comment: Then try using `if ($this->customer->isLogged() > 0)`